ROS2 slam_toolbox: Does removing nodes harm the overall map perfromance, when updating the area later on?
There a are two questions to this, the first is if removing nodes and then remapping the areas is hurting the map quality. I utilize the same function that the lifelong mapping uses to remove nodes and call it via a service that ether removes all nodes with hits in the area or all nodes of an area all together.
  /**
   * Updates a single cell's value based on the given counters
   * @param pCell
   * @param cellPassCnt
   * @param cellHitCnt
   */
  virtual void UpdateCell(kt_int8u * pCell, kt_int32u cellPassCnt, kt_int32u cellHitCnt)
  {
    if (cellPassCnt > m_pMinPassThrough->GetValue()) {
      kt_double hitRatio = static_cast<kt_double>(cellHitCnt) / static_cast<kt_double>(cellPassCnt);

      if (hitRatio > m_pOccupancyThreshold->GetValue()) {
        *pCell = GridStates_Occupied;
      } else {
        *pCell = GridStates_Free;
      }
    }
  }

Secondly, do all hits ever recorded by all nodes play into the hit_count/pass_count? So is the consequence of having 10 old nodes with 100 old hits that I would need 100 new nodes with 100 misses to remove an object?
/*****************************************************************************/
void SMapper::RemoveNodeScanFromGraph(
  karto::Vertex<karto::LocalizedRangeScan>* vertex)
/*****************************************************************************/
{
    mapper_->RemoveNodeFromGraph(vertex);
    mapper_->GetMapperSensorManager()->RemoveScan(vertex->GetObject());
    //TODO check if this is necessary or po
    //dataset_->RemoveData(vertex->GetObject());
    vertex->RemoveObject();
    delete vertex;
    vertex = nullptr;
    mapper_->ClearLocalizationBuffer();
}



the first is if removing nodes and then remapping the areas is hurting the map quality. I utilize the same function that the lifelong mapping uses to remove nodes and call it via a service that ether removes all nodes with hits in the area or all nodes of an area all together.

Unless you are very thoughtful about the connections of those nodes, how you're replacing them, and maintaining important constraints - yes you will probably hurt map quality.

do all hits ever recorded by all nodes play into the hit_count/pass_count? So is the consequence of having 10 old nodes with 100 old hits that I would need 100 new nodes with 100 misses to remove an object?

In a way, yes. You need to have "enough" new data to depreciate old data. That isn't necessarily 1:1 however, it depends on the ratio.

Thank you for the clarification, but if I remap the area again the new nodes form conections with the old ones, atleast in my setup it has not worsend the overall mapquality drasticly but I also might have missed important looplcosures etc. by shere luck. Do you have any recomendation on how to update maps partialy other than a complete remap? I thought about removing scans from nodes but the node decay through that, seems also quite daunting and I also havent looked too much into other implications of that. Maybe delete nodes with to much node decay when there is other nodes to cover for it.
